# How to upload file to box using python

Tags: python, jenkins

I am new to python and I want to know if we can upload files from our local system to box.com?
Or else can we take help from any mediator like Jenkins to upload this files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but there is a package for python to connect to the box platform through an API http://opensource.box.com/box-python-sdk/tutorials/intro.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below boxsdk library code.

```
def upload_file_to_box(client, folder_id, filename):
        folder = client.folder(folder_id=folder_id)
        items = folder.get_items()
        for item in items:
            if item.name == filename:
                updated_file = client.file(item.id).update_contents(item.name)
                print('File "{0}" has been updated'.format(updated_file.name))
                return
        uploaded_file = folder.upload(filename)
        print('File "{0}" has been uploaded'.format(uploaded_file.name))
```

This will check for a specific file name and compare it with all files names in the folder and updates a new version if exists, otherwise uploads a new file.

Also you can search the filename inside a folder using [search API](https://developer.box.com/reference/get-search/) by using the below code. But the search API has a time lag of 10 minutes or greater.

```
items = client.search().query(query='"{}"'.format(filename), limit=100, ancestor_folders=[folder])
```